# Error C3867 'DataBase::isUserAndPassMatch': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to membe

Tags: c++

Ive been trying to figure it out for a while but couldent find a solution.

When i write this code line in another cpp file:

```
if(DataBase::isUserAndPassMatch(u->getUsername(), " ")){}
```

I get Error C3867. i tried to switch u->getUsername() to empty string (" ") but still same error. I also tried this:

```
 if(&DataBase::isUserAndPassMatch(u->getUsername(), " ")){}
```

**isUserAndPassMatch:**

```
bool DataBase::isUserAndPassMatch(std::string username, std::string password){}
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` in the first bit of code.  Should be `if(DataBase::isUserAndPassMatch(u->getUsername(), " "))`

Comment: yep, just saw it. didnt fix the problem though

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have class definition:

```
class DataBase {
public
   bool isUserAndPassMatch() {return true;}
};
```

If you want to call the isUserAndPassMatch member function, you have to have object:

```
DataBase db;
if( db.isUserAndPassMatch() ) {
}
```

Try it.